# How to provide component for dynamic url in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am using Angular 7 in my application.
After user sign up user will get a mail in that mail Backend team providing some dynamic url.
like below

```
https://csrt.minn.ai/api/users/authenticate/9a4c790a-9a33-4d54-961a-683e144e4669
```

so How to provide component for that dynamic url.

Comment: You can pass this URL as a query parameter or as a callback in the Angular application URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcard routes to redirect all child routes of the authenticate to a specific route in `routing.module`, for example:

```
var routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        children: [
            {
                path: "authenticate",
                children: [
                    {
                        path: "someWhere", // or "" to root route of authentication
                        component: AuthenticateComponent
                    },
                    {
                        path: "**",
                        redirectTo: ""
                    }
                ]
             }
         ]
     }
]
```